# Updating Firebase info on focusout with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to update a users profile info that they're able to update at anytime. I'm displaying their profile info and I'm allowing them to update that info with a `contenteditable`, but I can't seem to update the info in Firebase.

**Basic HTML:**

```
<div class="white-container bottom-padding-fortypx container container-about margin-top-eightypx">

    <h6 class="margin-top-eightypx">company</h6>
    <h4 id="companyName" contenteditable="true"></h4>

    <h6>username</h6>
    <h4 id="username"></h4>

 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    $('#companyName').append('<p>' + snapshot.val().businessName + '</p>');
    $('#username').append('<p>' + snapshot.val().businessAddress + '</p>');
    $('#companyAddress').append('<p>' + snapshot.val().state + '</p>');

    var updatedInfo = document.getElementById('companyName');
    updatedInfo = updatedInfo.innerText;
    console.log(updatedInfo);

    var db = firebase.database();
    $('[contenteditable]').on('keypress focusout', function(en) {
      var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      db.ref('users' + currentUser.uid).update({'businessName': updatedInfo});
    })
  });
})
```

As you can see, I was trying to update the content after a `focusout` event has occurred once a user clicks out of the `contenteditable` field, however, no update is occurring in Firebase. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like when I check the value in the console when I added a console.log within the focusout event area, the focusout it's still showing the previous value still stored in Firebase.

Comment: You're missing a `/` after `'users'` in `db.ref('users' + currentUser.uid).update(...`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That helped and it did update in Firebase but what I had previously is now showing the same name but with Name\n\n

Comment: Ok, I added a work around to get rid of all the \n's however it's still not updating the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work around I was able to come up with a solution for my problem above (no change to my HTML):

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
   var updated = document.getElementById('name').value = this.innerText;
   // Getting rid of the new line characters, twice.
   if (updated[updated.length - 1] === '\n')
     updated = updated.slice(0, -2);
   // Pushing the updated profile information to their firebase profile
   db.ref('users/' + userId).update({
     'businessName': updated
   });
});
```

I added an / with what Frank suggested after 'users' which helped but using innerTest with contenteditable added two line breaks, therefore, I used this snippet to rid those:

```
if (updated[updated.length - 1] === '\n')
  updated = updated.slice(0, -2);
```

Now the actual value wasn't updating yet to the new value until I changed '.on' to '.addEventListener' and slightly changing up the code a bit.